# awk - Remove lines from a block with start and end words

Tags: awk

I have a file like below.

```
Line1
line2
Begin1
Select is running
Done1
Begin
Update is in progress
Done
Begin2
Select is running
Done2
Begin3
select is running
Done4
line last
```

I want to find the word update and delete that block starting from begin (the previous line) until the done (the next line)

So the final output will be

```
Line1
Line2
Begin1
Select is running
Done1
Begin2
Select is running
Done2
Begin3
select is running
Done4
line last
```

I used the following code to remove, but unfortunately, it removed all lines if it doesn't have the string Being and Done.

```
awk -i inplace  '/BEGIN/ {f=1} f {s=s?s"\n"$0:$0;if ($0~/update/) f=s=0} /COMMIT/ && f {print s;f=s=0}' filename


Begin1
Select is running
Done1
Begin2
Select is running
Done2
Begin3
select is running
Done4
```

#### Update:

another use case:

In case another file with the following structure,

```
Line1
line2
Begin
Select is running
Done
Begin
Done
Update is in progress
Begin2
Select is running
Done2
Begin3
select is running
Done4
line last
```

Here `Begin` and `Done` are coming before the `update`. So I want to remove those 3 lines. Any recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: The block you want to delete seems to be delimited by `Begin` and `Done` rather than by the same words with trailing digits. Is that always the case? Is there a reason you use very different delimiters for these lines? Is the data that you show the _actual_ data, or are you working with XML or some other structured document format? (It's easier to work with XML-aware tools when dealing with XML, and likewise for other structured document formats.)

Comment: This is a sample data, but there will be more Begin and Done block with `select`

Comment: @Kusalananda updated the question

Comment: what is the relation of your main question with the newly added use-case into it? I mean then what would happen to the role (delete if block contains `update` string)? are there any other use-cases that you didn't mention yet? for example one if `done` become before `begin`?

Comment: both are similar, 1st case: everything is structured `Begin... update... Done` but the 2nd case `Begin... Done... update`

Comment: Your code is testing for `/COMMIT/` and `/update/` but your data doesn't contain `COMMIT` or `update` anywhere (it does have `Update` though). Fix that and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

With this awk script saved to e. g. `717212.awk`:

```
BEGIN { p=1 }
/^Update/ { p=0 }
p { print $0 }
p==0 && /^Done/ { p=1 }
```

Then this should do what you request with given input file `inputfile`:

```
awk -f 717212.awk inputfile
```

The way it works is to simply lay out exactly what you want.  You want to print based on specific conditions, so we define at the `BEGIN`ning a variable, `p`, that keeps track of whether or not we want to print.

- When we see a line starting (`^`) with `Update`, we set `p` to `0`, indicating we do not want to print.
- We then `print` the input line if and only if `p` is true (i. e. non-zero).
- Finally, when we see a line starting with `Done` and we're currently not printing (which is to say, if `p` is equal to `0`), we set `p` to start printing again.

The key difference here is that the printing is done only *after* we're done determining whether or not we want to, but before we look to see whether we want to resume printing on the next line.

Comment: Oh great, just curious,  In case if want to do the same thing but this time the begin and done are coming before the update string. `Begin... Done.... update in progress`, so I want to remove this block from Begin to Done, what change can I make in the script. Happy to add this in the question as well.

Comment: All you need to do is adjust what is searched for on the "stop printing this" code and the "start printing after this" code.  If you want to exclude from `Begin` to `Done`, then change `^Update` to `^Begin`.

Comment: @TheDataGuy If you have clarification of your question, then please add these to the question rather than mentioning them in passing in a comment.

Comment: Updated the question with the use case